# Logs in mongoose with node 11.11 - All object model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, model

Good afternoon,

I go through the **11.11 version of NODEJS** this weekend.

When I used for example :

**User.findOne({_id}).then(user => console.log(user)**

That's simply sent me the user object and its data : 
**{
    _id: « daa8908908azdza » 
    name: « Jacks » 
}**

Now, it's return me all the model and the parameters.

How can I resolve this ? It's quite problematical

Thanks

Example of log user

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/11/2/1552403883-capture-d-ecran-2019-03-12-a-16-11-12.png

[tps://i.stack.imgur.com/B0KmY.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHxNg.png)

Comment: Example of log :

Comment: Please edit your question so as to include your code as text inside code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can select only some fields using :

```
User
   .findOne({_id})
   .select("name age")
   .then(user => console.log(user)) // { _id: "daa8908908azdza", name: "Jacks", age: 28 }
```

Note that the _id is always selected, if you don't want it you can explicitely unselect it :

```
.select("-_id name age") // { name: "Jacks", age: 28 }
```